# Correct use of the HAVING clause, to return the unique row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in this scenario:  `Teams`, `Players` and `PlayersInTeams`.

A `Player` is just a registered user.  No W/L data is associated with a `Player`.

A `Team` maintains win/loss records.  If a player is playing by himself, then he plays with his "solo" team (a `Team` with only that Player in it).  Every time Bob and Jan win together, their `Team` entry gets wins++.  Every time Jason and Tommy lose together, their Team entry gets losses++.

The `PlayersInTeams` table only has 2 columns, and it's an intersection table between `Players` and `Teams`:

```
> desc PlayersInTeams ;
+------------+---------+
| Field      | Type    |
+------------+---------+
| fkPlayerId | int(11) |
| fkTeamId   | int(11) |
+------------+---------+
```

So here is the tough part:

Because a `Player` can be part of multiple `Teams`, it is important to fetch the right `TeamId` from the `Teams` table at the beginning of a match.

A Player's SOLO team is given by

```
select fkTeamId from PlayersInTeams where
fkPlayerId=1 HAVING count(fkTeamId)=1;
```

NO IT'S NOT!!  But I don't understand why.

I'm trying to say:

> Get the fkTeamId from PlayersInTeams where
>   the fkPlayerId=1, but also, the count of rows
>   that have this particular fkTeamId is exactly 1.

The query returns (empty set), and actually if I change the HAVING clause to being incorrect (`HAVING count(fkTeamId)<>1;`), it returns the row I want.

Comment: This is not the proper usage of HAVING clause, it is to be used when using GROUPBY:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: @Ron.B.I MySQL accepts `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`, so the original query is valid.

Comment: I used the word proper for a reason [=

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your query, add a `group by`.  To compute the count per team, you'll need to change the `where` clause to return all teams that player 1 is on:

```
select  fkTeamId 
from    PlayersInTeams 
where   fkTeamId in
        (
        select  fkTeamId
        from    PlayersInTeams
        where   fkPlayerId = 1 
        )
group by
        fkTeamId
having  count(*) = 1;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fab2/1/0)

---

Below a detailed explanation of why your `count(*) = 1` condition works in a surprising way. When a query contains an aggregate like `count`, but there is no `group by` clause, the database will treat the entire result set as a single group.

In databases other than MySQL, you could not select a column that is not in a `group by` without an aggregate.  In MySQL, all those columns are returned with the first value encountered by the database (essentially a random value from the group.)

[For example:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a0d0/3/0)

```
create table YourTable (player int, team int);
insert YourTable values (1,1), (1,2), (2,2);

select  player
,       team
,       count(team)
from    YourTable
where   player = 2
```

-->

```
player   team    count(team)
1        1       1
```

The first two columns come from a random row with `player = 1`.  The `count(team)` value is 2, because there are two rows with `player = 1` and a non-null `team`.  The count says nothing about the number of players in the team.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural thing to do is to count the rows to see what is going on:

```
select fkTeamId, count(*)
from PlayersInTeams
where fkPlayerId=1
group by fkTeamId;
```

The `group by` clause is a more natural way to write the query:

```
select fkTeamId
from PlayersInTeams
where fkPlayerId=1
having count(fkteamid) = 1
```

However, if there is only one row for a player, then your original version should work -- the filtering would take it to one row, the fkTeamId would be the team on the row and the `having` would be satisfied.  One possibility is that you have duplicate rows in the data.

If duplicates are a problem, you can do this:

```
select fkTeamId
from PlayersInTeams
where fkPlayerId=1
having count(distinct fkteamid) = 1
```

EDIT for "solo team":

As pointed out by Andomar, the definition of *solo* team is not quite what I expected.  It is a player being the only player on the team.  So, to get the list of teams where a given player is the team:

```
select fkTeamId
from PlayersInTeams
group by fkTeamId
having sum(fkPlayerId <> 1) = 0
```

That is, you cannot filter out the other players and expect to get this information.  You specifically need them, to be sure they are not on the team.

If you wanted to get *all* solo teams:

```
select fkTeamId
from PlayersInTeams
group by fkTeamId
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Your `where` clause filters out records for all other players, so you can't see if a player is the single player of a team.

Comment: @Andomar . . . I understood the question to be whether one player is on one team or on multiple teams.  Perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The question says "the count of rows that have this particular fkTeamId is exactly 1."  I only noticed on second reading but it seems clear enough.

Comment: If you add `and fkPlayerId=1` to the last query, you can actually get the solo team as well.

Comment: +1 `having sum(fkPlayerId <> 1) = 0` concise way to write the query!  But not sargeable, so if there are indexes on `(fkPlayerId, fkTeamId)` and `(fkTeamId, fkPlayerId)`, I think my version would be faster.

Comment: @bobobobo . . . Well, I would add `max(fkPlayerId) = 1` because I am not a fan of "hidden columns" in aggregations.  That statement is also correct (and your way would work in MySQL too, even if I am biased against it).  I chose the first form to emphasize that the other players are needed for the query to work and can't be filtered out in a `where` clause.

Comment: [The execution plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d8791/3) for the last query here seems to be slightly better than the one with the subquery

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` is usually used with a `GROUP BY` statement - it's like a `WHERE` which gets applied to the *grouped* data.

```
SELECT fkTeamId
FROM PlayersInTeams
WHERE fkPlayerId = 1
GROUP BY fkTeamId
HAVING COUNT(fkPlayerId) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  It still returns multiple rows (e.g. teams 1 & 3), because I think the WHERE clause eliminates the duplicates... so by the time it gets down to HAVING clause, all of the teamIds DO have COUNT=1

Comment: Your `where` clause filters out records for all other players, so you can't see if a player is the single player of a team.

Answer (score 1):

SqlFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36530/21

Try finding teams with one player first, then using that to find the player id if they are in any of those teams:

```
select DISTINCT PlayersInTeams.fkTeamId
from (
  select fkTeamId 
  from PlayersInTeams
  GROUP BY fkTeamId
  HAVING count(fkPlayerId)=1
) AS Sub
INNER JOIN PlayersInTeams
  ON PlayersInTeams.fkTeamId = Sub.fkTeamId
WHERE PlayersInTeams.fkPlayerId = 1;
```

Comment: Corrected the "not the same as" sample

Comment: Your `where` clause filters out records for all other players, so you can't see if a player is the single player of a team.

Comment: @Andomar Yes, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @bobobobo. In that case find teams with a single player id first then do the player `where` outside everything else - code updated to reflect that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody's answers here were very helpful.  Besides missing `GROUP BY`, I found that my problem was mainly that my `WHERE` clause was "too early".

Say we had

```
insert into PlayersInTeams values
  (1, 1), -- player 1 is in solo team id=1
  (1, 2),(2,2) -- player 1&2 are on duo team id=2
;
```

Now we try:

```
select fkTeamId from PlayersInTeams
where fkPlayerId=1 -- X kills off data we need
group by fkTeamId
HAVING count(fkTeamId)=1;
```

In particular the `WHERE` was filtering the temporary resultset so that any row *that didn't have* `fkPlayerId=1` was being cut out of the result set.  Since each fkPlayerId is associated with each fkTeamId only once, of course the COUNT of the number of occurrences by fkTeamId is always 1.  So you always get back just a list of the teams *player 1 is part of*, but you still don't know his SOLO team.

Gordon's answer with my addendum

```
select fkPlayerId,fkTeamId
from PlayersInTeams
group by fkTeamId
having count(fkTeamId) = 1
and fkPlayerId=1 ;
```

Was particularly good because it's a cheap query and does what we want.  It chooses all the SOLO teams **first**, (chooses all fkTeamIds that only occur ONCE in the table (via `HAVING count(*)=1`)), *then from there* we go and say, "ok, now just give me the one that has this fkPlayerId=1".  And voila, the solo team.

DUO teams were harder, but similar.  The difficulty was similar to the problem above only with ambiguity from teams of 3 with teams of 2.  [Details in an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/662b9/2).