# Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I have upgraded my system and have installed MySql 5.7.9 with php for a web application I am working on. I have a query that is dynamically created, and when run in older versions of MySQL it works fine.  Since upgrading to 5.7 I get this error:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> non-aggregated column 'support_desk.mod_users_groups.group_id' which is
> not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Note the manual page for Mysql 5.7 on the topic of [Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

This is the query that is giving me trouble:

```sql
SELECT mod_users_groups.group_id AS 'value', 
       group_name AS 'text' 
FROM mod_users_groups
LEFT JOIN mod_users_data ON mod_users_groups.group_id = mod_users_data.group_id 
WHERE  mod_users_groups.active = 1 
  AND mod_users_groups.department_id = 1 
  AND mod_users_groups.manage_work_orders = 1 
  AND group_name != 'root' 
  AND group_name != 'superuser' 
GROUP BY group_name 
HAVING COUNT(`user_id`) > 0 
ORDER BY group_name
```

I don't understand `only_full_group_by` enough to figure out what I need to do to fix the query. Can I just turn off the `only_full_group_by` option, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: here I found solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7588442/612987

Comment: I had luck prefixing my select query with "create temporary table temp " then getting the result from a second query "select * from temp" and then a final query to clean up "drop table if exists temp". If this merits any rep, maybe I'll get enough to make this an answer.

Answer (score 408, accepted):

I would just add `group_id` to the `GROUP BY`.

When `SELECT`ing a column that is not part of the `GROUP BY` there could be multiple values for that column within the groups, but there will only be space for a single value in the results. So, the database *usually* needs to be told exactly how to make those multiple values into one value. Commonly, this is done with an aggregate function like `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `MAX()` etc... I say *usually* because most other popular database systems insist on this. However, in MySQL prior to version 5.7 the default behaviour has been more forgiving because it will not complain and then arbitrarily choose *any value*! It also has an `ANY_VALUE()` function that could be used as another solution to this question if you really needed the same behaviour as before. This flexibility comes at a cost because it is non-deterministic, so I would not recommend it unless you have a very good reason for needing it. MySQL are now turning on the `only_full_group_by` setting by default for good reasons, so it's best to get used to it and make your queries comply with it.

So why my simple answer above? I've made a couple of assumptions:

1) the `group_id` is unique. Seems reasonable, it is an 'ID' after all.

2) the `group_name` is also unique. This may not be such a reasonable assumption. If this is not the case and you have some duplicate `group_names` and you then follow my advice to add `group_id` to the `GROUP BY`, you may find that you now get more results than before because the groups with the same name will now have separate rows in the results. To me, this would be better than having these duplicate groups hidden because the database has quietly selected a value arbitrarily!

It's also good practice to qualify all the columns with their table name or alias when there's more than one table involved...

```sql
SELECT 
  g.group_id AS 'value', 
  g.group_name AS 'text' 
FROM mod_users_groups g
LEFT JOIN mod_users_data d ON g.group_id = d.group_id 
WHERE g.active = 1 
  AND g.department_id = 1 
  AND g.manage_work_orders = 1 
  AND g.group_name != 'root' 
  AND g.group_name != 'superuser' 
GROUP BY 
  g.group_name, 
  g.group_id 
HAVING COUNT(d.user_id) > 0 
ORDER BY g.group_name
```

Comment: In MySQL 5.7 they set a property that requires all non-aggregate fields in a query be a GROUP BY. So a query like SELECT a, SUM(b) FROM table; means that field "a" Must be in a GROUP BY. So if you don't have a GROUP BY then you must add it to the query. It is all about if you have at least one aggregate field in the SELECT portion of your query.

Answer (score 397):

You can try to disable the `only_full_group_by` setting by executing the following:

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

MySQL 8 does not accept `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` so that needs to be removed.

Comment: This is a work around, you better fix your query rather than silencing the warning

Comment: Updating the /etc/mysql/my.cnf (as seen below) is a more sustainable solution as the default settings tends to come back after restart. And for those that say you should fix the query, then that is not quite easy sometimes when you need a quick debugging query and do things like `SELECT COUNT(*), t.* FROM my_table t GROUP BY col` and you have 20-50 columns, do you want to spend that much time adding each column to the group by?

Comment: This "solution" is quite dangerous. You may activate modes you had disabled previously by blindly changing them instead of only removing the one settings flag in question. This may lead to unexpected behaviour and in worst case lead to wrong results or stop your app(s) from working entirely. Thus I consider this answer as wrong.

Comment: I made this persistent through refresh by figuring out my current sql_mode via `SELECT @@sql_mode;` and then adding the result from there to my.cnf: `sql_mode=[list of modes from query, minus ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY]`

Comment: "Fixing your query" is difficult when all queries were done years ago by another person who is not in the company anymore ;)

Comment: much better only change the modes you want, e.g. `set global sql_mode=concat(replace(@@global.sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_DATE',''),',STRICT_TRANS_TABLES')` (and same for `set session`/`@@session.sql_mode`)

Answer (score 366):

you can turn off the warning message as explained in the other answers or you can understand **what's happening** and fix it.

[As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) which means when you are grouping rows and then selecting something out of that groups, you need to **explicitly say which row** should that selection be made from.

For example, given these records:

| id | colour | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 1 |
| 2 | yellow | 4 |
| 3 | red | 8 |
| 4 | yellow | 9 |
| 5 | blue | 2 |
| 6 | red | 5 |
| 7 | blue | 3 |

We can ask MySQL to group by the colour field, giving us these groups:

| id | colour | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | yellow | 4 |
| 4 | yellow | 9 |

| id | colour | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | red | 8 |
| 6 | red | 5 |

| id | colour | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 1 |
| 5 | blue | 2 |
| 7 | blue | 3 |

But if we ask for the value field of each group, we'll get an error because each group has many rows with value fields.

Or, in image form: [image: Pictorial representation of the tables above]

MySQL needs to know which row in the group you're looking for, which gives you three options

- add the column you want to the group statement `group by rect.color, rect.value` which can be what you want in some cases but otherwise would return duplicate results with the same color which you may not want
- use MySQL's [**aggregate functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to indicate which value you are looking for inside the groups like `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `FIRST()`
- use [**`ANY_VALUE()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) if you are sure that all the results inside the group are the same.

Comment: For example you're selecting from `sales`, `salesitems` and `customers`. `sales` and `customers` are 1x1 and `sales` to `salesitems` is 1xN; Now because you're selecting multiple items everything in `sales` and `customers` will be repeated values per `salesitems`, if you group by `sales.id` to (for example) sum the sales Items values, you'll have to `ANY_VALUE` all `sales` and `customers` fields.

Answer (score 184):

If you don't want to make any changes in your current query then follow the below steps -

1. vagrant ssh into your box
2. Type: `sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. Scroll to the bottom of file and type `A` to enter insert mode
4. Copy and paste

   ```
   [mysqld]
   sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
   ```
5. Type `esc` to exit input mode
6. Type `:wq` to save and close vim.
7. Type `sudo service mysql restart` to restart MySQL.

Comment: Just a heads up to all Vagrant users trying to use this with AdonisJS you need this to run the `paginate` function.

Comment: This obviously is not only for Vagrant users, but any Unix system. Note that for me the location of the `my.cnf` file was `/etc`. Als note the new syntax since `MySQL 5.7.8:`
`sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

Comment: [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/bin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'

Comment: Remove NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER if you are using MYSQL 8.

Answer (score 108):

**Use `ANY_VALUE()` to refer to the nonaggregated column.**

```
SELECT name,           address , MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name; -- fails
SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name; -- works
```

From [MySQL 5.7 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> You can achieve the same effect without disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`
>   by using `ANY_VALUE()` to refer to the nonaggregated column.
>
> ...
>
> This query might be invalid with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled because the nonaggregated address column in the select list is not named in the `GROUP BY` clause:
>
> ```
> SELECT name, address, MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If you know that, for a given data set, each name value in fact uniquely determines the address value, address is effectively functionally dependent on name. To tell MySQL to accept the query, you can use the `ANY_VALUE()` function:
>
> ```
> SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
> ```

Comment: As someone who had been running into this issue for a while now - I especially like this solution because it doesn't require you to change any files or settings in your MySQL setup. 

Interestingly enough, I don't see `ANY_VALUE ` mentioned anywhere else in similar discussions - works perfectly for me with my `GROUP_BY` `contains nonaggregated column` error.

Answer (score 61):

I will try to explain you what this error is about.
Starting from MySQL 5.7.5, option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled by default.
Thus, according to standart SQL92 and earlier:

> does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition,
>   or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named
>   in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely
>   determined by) GROUP BY columns

([read more in docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html))

So, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` GROUP BY `name`;
```

You will get error message after executing query above.

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'testsite.user.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Why?
Because MySQL dont exactly understand, what certain values from grouped records to retrieve, and this is the point.

I.E. lets say you have this records in your `users` table:
[image: Yo]

And you will execute invalid query showen above.
And you will get error shown above, because, there is 3 records with name `John`, and it is nice, but, all of them have different `email` field values.
So, MySQL simply don't understand which of them to return in resulting grouped record.

You can fix this issue, by simply changing your query like this:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `users` GROUP BY `name`
```

Also, you may want to add more fields to SELECT section, but you cant do that, if they are not aggregated, but there is crutch you could use (but highly not reccomended):

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(`id`), ANY_VALUE(`email`), `name` FROM `users` GROUP BY `name`
```

[image]

Now, you may ask, why using `ANY_VALUE` is highly not recommended?
Because MySQL don't exactly know what value of grouped records to retrieve, and by using this function, you asking it to fetch any of them (in this case, email of first record with name = John was fetched).
Exactly I cant come up with any ideas on why you would want this behaviour to exist.
Please, if you dont understand me, read more about how grouping in MySQL works, it is very simple.

And by the end, here is one more simple, yet valid query.
If you want to query total users count according to available ages, you may want to write down this query

```
SELECT `age`, COUNT(`age`) FROM `users` GROUP BY `age`;
```

Which is fully valid, according to MySQL rules.
And so on.
It is important to understand what exactly the problem is and only then write down the solution.

Answer (score 43):

I am using Laravel 5.3, mysql 5.7.12, on laravel homestead (0.5.0, I believe)

Even after explicitly setting editing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to reflect:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I was still receiving the error.

I had to change `config/database.php` from `true` to `false`:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false, //behave like 5.6
        //'strict' => true //behave like 5.7
    ],
```

Further reading:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/set-set-sql-mode-on-homestead
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 30):

Go to mysql or phpmyadmin and select database,
then simply execute this query and it will work.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: would be nice if you provide some explanations what it does

Comment: @devnullΨ Its actually remove 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' from variables , you can find it in 
phpmyadmin > variable menu > sql_mode option
you can directly remove here

Comment: But the problem with the solution is every time I restart mysql I need to execute the query again. It means the solution is not permanent or persistent.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using wamp 3.0.6 or any upper version other than the stable 2.5 you might face this issue, firstly the issue is with sql . you have to name the fields accordingly. but there is another way by which you can solve it. click on green icon of wamp. mysql->mysql settings-> sql_mode->none. or from console you can change the default values.

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: fantastic, building on what he said, insert command `show variables like '%sql_mode%';` in mysql command line, sql_mode setting will expose

Answer (score 18):

Addition of lines (mention below) in file : /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Work fine for me. 
Server version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: are you using RDS?

Comment: @MubasshirPawle  No

Answer (score 10):

For mac:

1.Copy the default my-default.cnf to /etc/my.cnf

```
sudo cp $(brew --prefix mysql)/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

2.Change sql_mode in my.cnf using your favorite editor and set it to this

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

3.Restart MySQL server.

```
mysql.server restart
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well. But I use mysql default of Mac, so I don't have brew path. Just sudo cp my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf

Comment: @Mike Nguyen sudo cp /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf sudo vi /etc/my.cnf set sql_model sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION Restart MySQL server.

Answer (score 7):

This is what helped me to understand the entire issue:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20074634/1066234
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

And in the following another example of a problematic query.

**Problematic:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as attempts, SUM(elapsed) as elapsedtotal, userid, timestamp, questionid, answerid, SUM(correct) as correct, elapsed, ipaddress FROM `gameplay`
                        WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                        AND cookieid = #
```

**Solved by adding this to the end:**

```
  GROUP BY timestamp, userid, cookieid, questionid, answerid, elapsed, ipaddress
```

Note: See the error message in PHP, it tells you where the problem lies.

Example:

> MySQL query error 1140: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #4 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db.gameplay.timestamp'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by - Query: SELECT COUNT(*) as attempts, SUM(elapsed) as elapsedtotal, userid, timestamp, questionid, answerid, SUM(correct) as correct, elapsed, ipaddress FROM gameplay
>                               WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
>                               AND userid = 1

In this case, **expression #4** was missing in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 7):

For localhost / wampserver 3 we can set sql-mode = user_mode to remove this error:

```
click on wamp icon -> MySql -> MySql Setting -> sql-mode -> user_mode
```

then restart wamp or apache

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `unique index` to `group_id`; if you are sure that `group_id` is unique.

**It can solve your case without modifying the query**.

A late answer, but it has not been mentioned yet in the answers. Maybe it should complete the already comprehensive answers available. At least it did solve my case when I had to split a table with too many fields.

Comment: that will be good only if your data is actually unique by that group id

Answer (score 3):

If you have this error with **Symfony** using **doctrine query builder**, and if this error is caused by an **orderBy** :

Pay attention to `select` the column you want to `groupBy`, and use `addGroupBy` instead of `groupBy` :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('smth')->addGroupBy('smth.mycolumn');
```

Works on **Symfony3** -

Answer (score 3):

I had to edit the below file on my Ubuntu 18.04:

`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

with

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

and

`sudo service mysql restart`

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not using your exact SQL

I used this query to overcome the Mysql warning.

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt, `regions_id`
FROM regionables 
WHERE `regionable_id` = '115' OR `regionable_id` = '714'
GROUP BY `regions_id`
HAVING cnt > 1
```

note the key for me being

```
count(*) AS cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

The consensus answer above is good but if you've got problems running queries within stored procedures after fixing your my.cnf file, then try loading your SPs again.

I suspect MySQL must have compiled the SPs with the default only_full_group_by set originally. Therefore, even when I changed my.cnf and restarted mysqld it had no effect on the SPs, and they kept failing with "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column  ... which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".

Reloading the SPs must have caused them to be recompiled now with only_full_group_by disabled. After that, they seem to work as expected.